# Using library chart as dependency in application chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have created a Library chart and uploaded to a GitLab repository. I have also created a package of that library chart and put that in the same repository.

Now, I am creating a application chart and I want to add the library chart as a dependency. But, while doing that I am getting error.

I have tried adding the Gitlab repo as a dependency in application chart.

```
dependencies:
  - name: helm-libraryChart
    version: 0.1.6
    repository: https://gitlab.com/....../helm-base/-/tree/main
```

and try "helm dependency build" command.

It's giving error:

```
Getting updates for unmanaged Helm repositories... update ./plexus-brand-service                                                                        1 ✘ ╱ dev ⎈ ╱ 10:08:04 AM 
...Unable to get an update from the "https://gitlab.com/...../helm-base/-/tree/main" chart repository:
        failed to fetch https://gitlab.com/....../helm-base/-/tree/main/index.yaml : 503 Service Unavailable
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "plexus-helm-repo" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Error: no cached repository for helm-manager-732a2d2ce82dd5555f40999b4534b023fc381cd8881fe27ac73bceda9e07b27a found. (try 'helm repo update'): open /Users/neeraj.yadav/Library/Caches/helm/repository/helm-manager-732a2d2ce82dd5555f40999b4534b023fc381cd8881fe27ac73bceda9e07b27a-index.yaml: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you use a command-line tool like `curl`, or a plain Web browser, to access that GitLab URL?  Are you sure you have the URL correct?  An HTTP 503 error isn't normally something you could fix from your end without being the people running the server.